# If the flux of a vector field $F$ is zero for ANY surface $S$ then is $F$ zero?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-fields, divergence-operator

If $\vec F$ is a vector field defined in a open (contractible) set $U$ of $\Bbb R^3$ such that
$$
\int_S\vec F\cdot\hat ndS=0
$$
for **ANY** surface $S$ then in particular the last equality holds for the boudray of a ball $B$ of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$ so that by the divergence theorem it must be
$$
\int_B\text{div}\vec F=0
$$
and thus by the main value integral theorem it follows that
$$
\text{div}\vec F=0
$$
so that there exist a vector field $\vec\Phi$ whose curl is $\vec F$ but unfortunately I do not see if this implies that $\vec F$ is zero or equivalentely that $\vec\Phi$ is constant. So could some one help me, please?

Comment: Consider $F = a \hat{x} + b \hat{y} + c \hat{z}$ with $a$, $b$ and $c$ constants not depending on location.

Comment: @AHusain Sorry, I do not understand your hint: could you explain better, please?

Comment: The vector field $\vec F$ does not have to be zero or constant.

Comment: @MathLover Could you explain better, please? So the statement is false?

Comment: @MathLover I do not understand the counterexample: indeed the flux of the costant vector field $\vec F:=(0,0,1)$ through the circle is not zero, right?

Comment: If you have a constant vector field in 3D, its flux through a _closed_ surface will be zero. But vice versa is not true. If flux through the closed surface is zero, does not mean vector field is constant or zero. Take vector field $(y, z, x)$ for example.

Comment: @Mathlover Okay, but in the question I do not say that the flux of $F$ is zero only for closed surfaces: it is zero for **ANY** surfcace!

Comment: Then $\vec F$ should be zero

Comment: @Mathlover Okay, but how prove it? Could you do this?

Comment: As it had been pointed out to you already, the mistake in your logic is that the divergence theorem can not be applied in all cases, as it is only valid for a very specific set of surfaces (simply connected I believe? the point is, it should be a closed surface), and a set of very specific vector fields (continuously differentiable). I guess a 'proof' should go along the lines of: if the scalar product of your vector field with ANY surface norm vector has to give zero, this implies that the field is uniformly zero. This, of course, has to be made exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for any surface $S$, then $F$ has to be $0$, and the things you claim are equivalences aren't actually equivalent. Firstly, you've lost some information because you went from ALL surfaces to only those which are the boundary of something else (so that you can apply the divergence theorem). Next, from $\text{div}(F)=0$ it does not follow it has a vector potential defined on all of $U$ (Poincare's lemma only gives the local existence of such a vector potential), nor does it follow that $F=0$. The answer to your title question is yes

Here's an almost complete outline for proving $F=0$. Suppose contrapositively that there is a point $p\in U$ where $F(p)\neq 0$. Define the unit vector $\nu(p):=\frac{F(p)}{\|F(p)\|}$. The mapping $x\mapsto G(x):=\langle F(x),\nu(p) \rangle$ is continuous on $U$, and $G(p)=1>0$. So, by continuity of $G$, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$, contained in $U$, such that $G>\frac{1}{2}$ on $V$. Therefore if we choose the surface $S$ to be _______________ then $\int_SF\cdot n\, dS$ is ___________. Fill in the blanks yourself.

Comment: So if we choose the surface $S$ to be a circle centered at $P$ and contined in the intersection of $V$ and a plane whose normal is $\nu(p)$ then $$\int_S F\cdot\hat n\ge\int_S \frac{1}2=\frac{1}2\cdot\text{Area}(S)\neq0 $$ that is impossible, right?

Comment: I think you mean "disk" rather than "circle".

Comment: @JohnHughes Oh yeah! My bad, sorry.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I assume you meant "a disk...whose normal is $\nu(p)$..." Then yes, the integral is non-zero and your estimation of the integral is correct. Just a small nitpick about "that is impossible". The way I wrote my answer, it was phrased as a contrapositive proof, not a proof by contradiction. So, saying $\int_SF\cdot n\,dS\neq 0$ already completes the proof. If you want to write it up as a proof by contradiction, that's also fine, but of course your phrasing would have to be slightly different.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay, thanks too much for your assistance!!! See you soon.

Answer (score 1):

If the integral is zero for *any* surface $S$ (e.g., an arbitrarily small disk or rectangle in any orientation), then the claim is true, and @peek-a-boo shows how you might demonstrate that.

If what you meant was "for any *closed* surface $S$" (i.e., surface-without-boundary, like a sphere or a torus), then the claim is false, for an everywhere constant field like $F(x, y, z) = (1, 0, 0)$ has the property that its integral over any closed surface is zero.

Comment: Okay, and is correct my commment is the @peek-a-boo's answer?