# A question on application on Stokes

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

> Prove that a necessary and sufficient condition that $\int_C\vec{F}$
> $\cdot d\vec{r} = 0 $ for every closed curve  C lying in a simply
> connected region R is that $\nabla \times F= 0 $  identically .

Sufficient part is straight forward application of Stokes theorem .
For the necessary part , lets try to prove it by contradiction.If we assume that $\nabla \times F $is not $0$ at some point in the space . By continuity , i think that we can ensure that there exists a neighbourhood where $\nabla \times F $ is not $0$ . Can we then say that there **'definitely'** exists a surface in that neighbourhood where the flux is non-zero . Intuition says that we can , but can we prove it more rigourously ! ?

Comment: Try to find a potential $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi=F$. To do this, fix a point $x_0\in R$ where you set $\phi(x_0)=0$ and determine the value of $\phi(x)$ for all other $x \in R$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus along a curve connecting $x$ with $x_0$.

Comment: Try to adapt the reasoning I presented in the following answer [If the flux is zero for any surface then is F zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185069/568204)

Comment: I don't think you *need* to prove it any more rigorously than you have suggested; the crux of the proof is the continuity step which you have outlined.  Everything else is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo , fill in the blanks part was nice.