# Proof that $\nabla \times E = 0$ using Stokes's theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

Firstly, I know that this can be proved by showing the curl of a gradient is $0$. I am not interested in that. I am interested in the validity of using Stokes's theorem. One way that Jackson proves that $\nabla \times E = 0$ is the following:

$$ F = q E $$

$$ W = - \int_A^B F \cdot dl = - q \int_A^B E \cdot dl = q \int_A^B \nabla \phi \cdot dl = 
 q \int_A^B d \phi = q(\phi_B - \phi_A) $$

so $\int_A^B E \cdot dl = -(\phi_B - \phi_A)$ therefore $\oint_A^B E \cdot dl = 0$

Then using Stokes's theorem $\int (\nabla \times E) \cdot \hat{n} da = 0$ which implies $\nabla \times E=0$.

Isn't the last line true only if $\nabla \times E \geq 0$? It seems like Jackson is instantiating $\int f(x) dx = 0 \implies f(x) = 0$, but this isn't guaranteed unless we already know $f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: His name was "Stokes", not "Stoke".

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is using the fact that closed curve line integrals of conservative vector fields are equal to $0$.

By Stokes' Theorem we have;

$$\int_{S}(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS=\oint_{\partial S}F\cdot ds$$

But for any $F=\nabla\phi$ where $\phi$ is a scalar field, we have;

$$\oint_{\partial S}F\cdot ds=0$$

So by Stokes' theorem it follows, by necessity, that;

$$\int_{S}(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS=0$$

$\textbf{EDIT}:$

If $(\nabla \times F)$ were not equal to zero everywhere in the interior of our closed contour then it would be possible to restrict our open surface to the neighborhood $M \subset S$ in which $|(\nabla \times F)|\geq 0$. This would lead to;

$$\oint_{\partial M}F\cdot dm \not = 0$$

Which is not possible for $F= \nabla\phi$.

Comment: This misses what I am asking. I am asking to prove that the last equation proves $\nabla \times F = 0$.

Comment: @ngc1300 Sorry about that... Jumped the gun on answering. Hope the edit makes it more helpful.

Comment: To clarify: The surface $S$ isn't closed.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Very true... Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

He's using that the line integral vanishes for all nice curves, so the surface integral vanishes for all "nice surfaces" (whose boundaries are said curves) and **this** is what allows us to prove the integrand vanishes. If we only have an integral equal to $0$ for one surface, then of course we can't say anything about the integrand; but here it's $0$ for "all nice surfaces".

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185069/568204) is actually an almost complete outline of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is that the above argument is true for all possible regions, which implies the claim. Here is a rigorous version of this:

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and that $$\int_E f=0 $$

for all measurable sets $E$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere

Proof:

Let $ U = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t } f(x)>0 \}$

Suppose $\mu(U)>0$ then there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t } f(x)>1/n \}$ and $\mu(U_n)>0$ hence

$$\int_U f \ge \int_{U_n}f \ge \dfrac{1}{n} \mu(U_n) \gt0$$

Contradicting our assumption.

In general you decompose $f=f_+ +f_-$ and apply the above argument to each function sparately. So in conclusion you'll have that:

$$ U_+ = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t } f(x)>0 \}$$

$$ U_- = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t } f(x)<0 \}$$

Both have zero measure hence $f=0$ almost everywhere. Since in physics we assume at least continuity then $f=0$ everywhere.

The above can be easily generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$; in fact, the argument looks exactly the same with the only difference being the domains.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it doesn't really make sense to say that $\nabla \times E \ge 0$, since $\nabla \times E$ isn't a real number (it's an element of $\mathbb R^3)$.

What Jackson's using here is continuity of $\nabla \times E$.
Let's suppose there's some point $p$ at which $F:=\nabla \times E \ne 0$. WLOG, we can assume $p$ is the origin and that the x-component of $F$ is positive. Then, by continuity, there is a disk $D$ about $0$ in the $x=0$ plane on which the x-component of $F$ is positive. We see that $\int_{D} F.n \cdot \mathrm{dA} > 0$ since the integrand is positive over this region. But this is a contradiction to what you've already proven.